# Meaning of double square brackets in bash

Tags: bash

At this [question in the answer from Kyle Brandt](https://serverfault.com/questions/53577/linux-bash-syntax-meaning-of-and) the `[[ ]]` construct is described as a "bash built-in test command".  The following is shown as an example.

```
  if [[ ( $a -gt 2 ) && ( $a -lt 5 ) ]]; then ...
```

Why are double square brackets, literally `[[ ]]`, necessary?

Answer (score 10):

[[ is a much more versatile version of [ in bash.

For example, Using the [[ ... ]] test construct, rather than [ ... ] can prevent many logic errors in scripts. For example, the &&, ||, <, and > operators work within a [[ ]] test, despite giving an error within a [ ] construct.

also, their implementations are different

```
-bash-3.2$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
-bash-3.2$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
```

Refer [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) for a good explanation

Comment: It's worse than that; `[ "$this" > "$that" ]` won't give an error, it'll just do something completely different from what you expected. (Specifically: it'll redirect output to the file specified by `$this`, then test whether `$that` is nonblank.)

Answer (score 3):

`[[ ]]` are equal to `test` keyword.

You can also use `[ ]` but `[[ ]]` isn't compatible with all shell types

To me, if I understand the real sense of question, question itself isn't well-formulated.
Those brackets have to be here not so much for order determination, but because the bash synopsis require them

## Edit

Question is changed, so my answer too.

`[[ ]]` is used against `[ ]` because you don't have to worry about quoting the left hand side of the test that will be read as a variable.
Moreover, `<` and `>` doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: If I can use `[ ]`, are you saying there is never a reason to use `[[ ]]`.

Comment: You're right, the order of operations has nothing to do with the question so I edited the question to remove any mention of `( )` determining the order of operations.

Comment: @broiyan: if you haven't to worry about being portable, someone supports that `[[ ]]` is better because you don't have to worry about quoting the left hand side of the test will be read as a variable. Moreover, `<` and `>` doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: @broiyan: take a look at my update

Comment: A quick scroll through this link http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest does not seem to turn up any information on why one would double the square brackets.  I don't know what you mean by the "left hand side" of the test.

Comment: @broiyan: yes, it was a typo. However, try it yourself and you'll discover that what I told you is real :)