# -bash: [: @: binary operator expected

Tags: bash, error-handling

all,

I am checking the error info in a file in the last line, I would like to have a "yes" result if there is an "Error". My shell script is like below:

```
[ $(tail -1 error.log | grep -E "Error") ] && echo "yes"
```

then I got the error like above in the title:

```
-bash: [: @: binary operator expected
```

The error message in the last line is like below:

```
[aaa,bbb,ccc, Error.ddd @ ]
```

I think that is because of the the Error message, which has [ @ ] format content caused this error. But I do not know how to fix it. Is there any one knows how to process this [ @ ] problem. Thanks very much

@csiu, thanks very much for your quick reply.

The trick here is to use double "[" as below:

```
 [[ $(tail -1 error.log | grep -E "Error") ]] && echo "yes"
```

Comment: `[ ]` is to do some comparison and you are just giving one piece of text, so for bash `[ @ ]` is not something it can interpret.

Comment: what about using double "[" and "]"? `[[ $(tail -1 error.log | grep -E "Error") ]] && echo "yes"`

Comment: @fedorqui, I think grep -E is for comparison.

Comment: `-E` instructs `grep` to use extended regular expressions; it's unnecessary here since `Error` has the same meaning whether it is interpreted as a basic or extended regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additionally to @csiu's answer, don't need the `test` command at all. You can operate based on grep's exit status:

```
tail -1 error.log | grep -qE "Error" && echo yes
```

Use `-q` to silence the output from grep. It's also more efficient because grep will exit immediately once the pattern is found.

---

Since we only have one line of input, we don't even need grep:

```
[[ $(tail -1 error.log) == *Error* ]] && echo yes
```

Comment: In hindsight, efficiency is not relevant since we only have one line of input

Comment: @ glenn, great, that is my original idea, to hide the output of grep. but do not know "-q" option here. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 5):

*well since my comment works, might as well post it in the answer section ;)*

Use double "[["

```
[[ $(tail -1 error.log | grep -E "Error") ]] && echo "yes"
```

Related posts:

- [How to use double or single bracket, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces)
- [Meaning of double square brackets in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496428/meaning-of-double-square-brackets-in-bash)